# Dual Monitor with Different Refresh Rates

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

I have a dual monitor setup, 1 is an LCD monitor with a refresh rate of 60. The other is an old CRT monitor with a refresh rate of 75. I have an Nvidia GeForce GT 430. My main display which is the LCD is plug into the DVI port of the graphics card using a DVI-to-VGA adapter since my LCD monitor is VGA and the CRT monitor is plug into the VGA port. Can this setup harm my graphics card in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the monitors are driven at a resolution and refresh rate that is within their specification there should be no problem.

As an example, I am currently driving 2 monitors with a stretched display at 2560x1024 @60Hz and a separate CRT monitor on 1024x768 @70Hz

EDIT: missed off the important bit, all of my monitors are using vga/adapters

Comment: I think my CRT monitor is only allowed at 75 since I cannot change it in any way. I'm just confused about this refresh rates, I thought it could damage my graphics card if they are not in the same rates.

Comment: The graphics card has two output drivers. They can work independently of each other which allows them to work at different resolutions and frequencies.

Comment: Thank you for the response Tog, now I'm confident with the setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ran 2 different tft monitors for ~1 year on 60 and 70Hz and did not encounter any problems. Thus I assume that there is no problem.